# Why is it called a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology, holomorphic-functions

Why is it called a Holomorphic function? The "Holo" means "entire" and "morphē" means "form" or "apparence", cf [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Terminology). I understand the "entire", because a holomorphic function is differentiable on the entire complex plane, but why "form", or "apparence"?

Comment: Actually, a holomorphic function is not necessarily defined on the entire complex plane. An [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) is, however.

Comment: In french, "entire" is translated as "entier", and "integer" also as "entier". Since an holomorphic function is a function that can be represented locally by a serie with integer powers of the variable and that French people worked a lot on them, may be the reason is there ? It would say that an holomorphic function has locally the appearance of  a "série entière" (which is the name for power series in french).

Answer (score 6):

*Not yet a definitive answer, but this should narrow the search.*

The Wikipedia article tells us the term "holomorphic function" (*fonction holomorphe* in french) was coined by Briot and Bouquet.

Actually, they published together several works on elliptic functions, so we may investigate this a bit. Here are two references:

- 1858, [Théorie des fonctions doublement périodiques et, en particulier, des fonctions elliptiques](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99569b)
- 1875, [Théorie des fonctions elliptiques, deuxième édition](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99571w)

In both books, they introduce several kinds of functions in the begining, and then procede to study periodic and doubly periodic functions. The vocabulary has changed completely in the meantime:

- A function whose values do not depend on the path followed by the complex variable is called ***monodrome*** in the first book, ***monotrope*** in the second.
- A function which has a complex derivative is called ***monogène*** in the first book, no term is given in the second.
- A function which is both ***monodrome*** and ***monogène*** is called ***synectique*** in the first book, while a function which is both ***monotrope*** and has a complex derivative is called ***holomorphe*** (holomorphic) in the second.

[This](https://books.google.fr/books?id=G8PE1fitymUC) recent book on the history on noneuclidean geometry tells us [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=G8PE1fitymUC&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q&f=false) that Cauchy coined both terms *monogène* and *holomorphe*. However, Cauchy died in 1857, so it looks awkward that Briot and Bouquet changed the terms after the first edition, following Cauchy who was already dead. On the other hand, given that the terminology wasn't apparently completely stabilized, Cauchy might have given the vocabulary earlier.

See also this question on HSM.SE: [First papers on holomorphic functions](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/first-papers-on-holomorphic-functions).